Ruby and Microsoft Entra ID
We have a Ruby web apllication which is registrated in Azure Microsoft Entra ID.
We registered the application but it doen't work.

AADSTS650053: The application 'Application' asked for scope
'a423023b-538a-4c96-af1d-07eb7c9d8f83' that doesn't exist on the
resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app
vendor.

API Permission is set to the default Microsoft.Graph Delegated User.Read.
Authentication Redirect URIs is http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc, Implicit grant and hybrid flows is ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows).
UPDATE


Can you paste the screenshot of the API permissions blade and the scope you are passing while generating the token?

Hi Rukmini, What scope, please?

While generating the token what is the value you pass for the scope parameter

Or can you include the code
